# ":XML on" does not work and gives syntax error

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlcmd

Simply, my problem is that when I try to apply ":XML on" on the first of my query, I get a syntax error as in the below screenshot. I work on SQL Server 2012

[The query and corresponding syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VttgQ.png)

The whole query is:

```
:XML ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT distinct 1 as Tag,
   NULL as Parent,  
   NULL AS [ExamTypes!1],
   NULL as [ExamType!2!ExamTypeID],  
   NULL       as [Template!3!ShortString],  
   NULL       as [Template!3!Order] 
  .
  .
  .
  (sum code)
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Any help ?

Comment: What are trying to do. There is no such option in `SQL SERVER`

Comment: If you want to convert the data to `xml` try [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178107.aspx)

Comment: Where did you see an ":XML ON" command in T-SQL reference or SQL Server tools?

Comment: according to the following path, :XML ON is used with FOR XML, and this is what i try to do:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx#OutputXML

Comment: i need to build a query that generates XML to be called in batch file using sqlcmd.

Comment: I edited the post adding the code for more clarification

Comment: @AhmedHamouda, it seems you may be running the query from SSMS.  In that case, you need to specify SQLCMD mode from the query menu (Query-->SQLCMD Mode).

Comment: @DanGuzman yes it is. it works fine now, thank you

Comment: @DanGuzman How to sign your comment as the answer ?

Comment: @AhmedHamouda, I added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you may be running the query from SSMS. `:FOR XML` is a SQLCMD command so you need to specify SQLCMD mode when the query is run from SSMS.  This can be done from the query menu (Query-->SQLCMD Mode).